# PHP Exec - How to only display the result of the last command

Tags: php, shell, exec

I'm using `exec` php function to run a script that grabs a YouTube video in mp3 format (with `youtube-dl`).

At the end of this script I made an `echo`, this is the result I want.

But when I launch my php page, the output is composed of everything `youtbe-dl` did. Like that:

```
    [youtube] zTkS9SvhHUI: Downloading webpage
    [youtube] zTkS9SvhHUI: Downloading video info webpage
    [youtube] zTkS9SvhHUI: Extracting video information
    [youtube] zTkS9SvhHUI: Downloading js player en_US-vflgFv_Kx
    [youtube] zTkS9SvhHUI: Downloading js player en_US-vflgFv_Kx
    [download] Destination: /var/www/xxx/mp3dl/Kaskade - Whatever Ft KOLAJ (NEUS Remix).webm 
    [download] 0.0% of 3.84MiB at 10.17KiB/s ETA 06:26 
    [download] 0.1% of 3.84MiB at 30.44KiB/s ETA 02:09 
    [. . .] 
    [download] 100.0% of 3.84MiB at 4.01MiB/s ETA 00:00 
    [download] 100% of 3.84MiB in 00:00
    [ffmpeg] Destination: /var/www/xxx/mp3dl/Kaskade - Whatever Ft KOLAJ (NEUS Remix).mp3
    Deleting original file /var/www/xxx/mp3dl/Kaskade - Whatever Ft KOLAJ (NEUS Remix).webm (pass -k to keep)
    /var/www/xxx/mp3dl/Kaskade - Whatever Ft KOLAJ (NEUS Remix).mp3
```

The only thing I need is :

```
/var/www/xxx/mp3dl/Kaskade - Whatever Ft KOLAJ (NEUS Remix).mp3
```

How can I do that? Is there something I did not understand?

**EDIT :** There is my php code :

```
$url = htmlspecialchars($_POST['url']);
$choice1 = $_POST['choice1'];
$output = exec('sh scripts/ytdlmp3_direct.sh "'.$url.'"');
if(isset($_POST['action'])){
    if(empty($url)) {
        print("<div class='card-panel yellow'>Please add a URL</div>")  ;
    } else {
        if($choice1 == "download") {
            print $output;
        } elseif($choice1 == "store") {
            print "Soon";
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!
~Quentin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **-q** OR **--quiet** to your command via `exec()` and it will not output any of the "debug" messages.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#verbosity--simulation-options)

> -q, --quiet Activate quiet mode